# XML Updation changes in Magento 2.1

Tags: magento2

Am unable to remove the footer links from deafault.xml page using remove tag.

```
<referenceBlock name="logo" remove="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Footer links name is

```
footer_links
```

So

```
<referenceBlock name="footer_links" remove="true"/>
```